# OpenCV and Pcl builds on OSX result in malformed object (load command ## cmdsize is zero)

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, cmake

Since a few weeks back I keep getting "malformed object" errors when building OpenCV or Pcl on OSX with CUDA libraries on (For some reason this doesn't happen when CUDA is disabled). During install phase the following error message is displayed (for different command #s):

**install_name_tool: object: libopencv_cudev.3.0.0.dylib malformed object (load command 19 cmdsize is zero)**

Although the build and install process finishes, the resulting libraries are malformed and can be linked but not loaded by other projects.

Additional info: My system is OSX Maverick 10.9.2, I use system libraries and tools as much as possible (clang, libjpeg etc.) and Macports for most other libraries that OpenCV etc. depend on (cmake etc.). Although the error seems to be linked to CUDA-related builds it probably isn't since manual compilation of small CUDA-projects works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved this problem but thought it might be nice to share and to document the solution:

**Problem:**

Bug in cmake 2.8.12+ - http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14707

**Explanation as far as I got it:**

This problem is not at all related to CUDA or mixed toolchains as I first thought. The reason for why this problem appears in the CUDA-builds is because in those specific builds install_name_tool is run to change the RPATH of CUDA libraries. The error is due to cmake corrupting the binaries and libs by adding two identical `LC_RPATHs` - it seems to come from when two `link_directories()` are resolved to the same final path (different macro resolutions). When install_name_tool is run on libs that have two identical `LC_RPATHs`, it then seems to corrupt them.

**Solutions:**

1. Guaranteed to work (tested): downgrade to cmake 2.8.11
2. Likely to work: Upgrade to cmake post this commit: http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commit;h=08141a5

**Step-by-step, solution 1 for Macports users:**

```
cd some_folder_that_you_keep_source_folders_in
sudo port uninstall cmake
svn co -r 110530 http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/devel/cmake
cd cmake
sudo port install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in a different project and managed to mitigate it by adding the following like to the CMakeLists.txt file:

> SET(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE)

Does it work for your case?